# NIntegrate options that work better for NExpectation[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4]^2

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

The problem below fails to converge to default accuracy using default method.

```
With[{a = 1 - 1/100000}, 
 NExpectation[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4]^2, 
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], WorkingPrecision -> 100]]
```

The warning I get is that

```
following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly \
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small
```

I think I can rule out "working precision" and value of integrand is 0....what should I do if it's highly oscillatory?

More generally I'm trying to plot this expectation as a function of $a$ and end up with fractal-like structure in the plot. Trying to figure out if it's really there, or whether it's artifact of default numerical integration method.

```
obj[a_] := NExpectation[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4]^2, 
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]];
Plot[obj[a], {a, 0.75, 1.2}]
```

[image]

**Edit** after letting it run overnight, original plot seems to be due to numerical issues

```
Clear[x];
term[a_] := 
  TransformedDistribution[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4], 
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]];
mean[a_] := 
  NExpectation[q, q \[Distributed] term[a], 
   Method -> {"NIntegrate", {MinRecursion -> 9, 
      MaxRecursion -> 30}}];
mean2[a_] := 
  NExpectation[q^2, q \[Distributed] term[a], 
   Method -> {"NIntegrate", {MinRecursion -> 9, MaxRecursion -> 30}}];
```

[image]

Comment: If you increase the accuracy of `NExpectation` it should compute a smoother graph and need to evaluate `obj` at fewer points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By increasing the number of allowed bisections you can make it work. You can even reduce the WorkingPrecision to the default value:

```
With[{a = 1 - 1/100000}, 
 NExpectation[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4]^2, 
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
  Method -> {"NIntegrate", {MinRecursion -> 12, MaxRecursion -> 30}}]]

(* 4.59843 *)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip...indeed the jagginess seem to be numeric artifacts

Comment: @DanielHuber, Reduction of workingPrecision to default value seems to less.  Difference to  `With[{a = 1 - 1/100000}, 
 NExpectation[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4]^2, 
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
  Method -> {"NIntegrate", {MinRecursion -> 12, MaxRecursion -> 30}}]]` can not realy be neglected. Yields `4.59996306650049691893344677743`

Comment: O course, I only pointed at the fact that it evaluates with default precision. Question is if this is good enough for you or not. In any case higher working precision means higher precision of the result.